# ubuntu 10.04 automated LAMP configuration script with virtual hosts

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, automation

I am looking for a set of bash scripts which can help me to automate the procedure of getting LAMP server up and running.

Typically what I am looking for is boot a VPS (say linode) with Ubuntu 10.04, upload the script with ssh and run it. The end product should be a properly configured LAMP server with virtual hosts.

Can somebody point me to a trusted source to obtain such a script?

Regards,

Pritam.

Comment: what exactly do you want this script to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Ansible](http://ansible.github.com/), which is a far simpler implementation of configuration management than Chef or Puppet, it doesn't require anything except SSH access to the server.

> Ansible is a radically simple model-driven configuration management, deployment, and command execution framework. Other tools in this space have been too complicated for too long, require too much bootstrapping, and have too much learning curve. Ansible is dead simple and painless to extend.

I have created a playbook for setting up a [LAMP server on Ubuntu 12.04](https://github.com/fourkitchens/server-playbooks) that you can use as a base for your own. Take a look, it's all YAML and Python syntax, very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com).  Its probably the most widely used solution for what you are trying to do.  Its probably going to be much more complex to get started than what you are looking for, but unfortunately, since so many hosting deployments are unique, I think you are going to have trouble finding a magic bullet to your solution.

If you don't like the looks of puppet, there are other similar solutions, such as [cfengine](http://cfengine.com/) or [chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Checked them out. All of them seem to full blown server management solutions. All I need is handy bash/perl script which I can modify on my own. I searched the net a lot, but Google has let me down on this one.